# How can I populate a user defined table quickly?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a generic histogram function to obtain histogram data for an arbitrary table in my db.

My db has many tables, each one is roughly a few gigs in size.  Only some of the columns are numeric.

I started off by trying to pass in a user defined table valued parameter.  The signature for my user defined function looked something like this:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.numArray AS TABLE (
    number  real NOT NULL
);

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_numericHistogram (
    @values dbo.numArray READONLY,
    @numOfBreaks int = 10,
    @rangeMin float = NULL,
    @rangeMax float = NULL
)
```

That worked, but it did not meet my performance requirements because I had to insert the existing numeric column into my user defined table first.  That takes a long time.  This long-running insertion happened inside the calling stored procedure, and looks something like this:

```
DECLARE @TVP AS dbo.numArray;

 -- Takes far too long
    INSERT INTO @TVP (number)
        SELECT myNumericColumn
        FROM dbo.SomeLargeTable;

EXEC dbo.fn_numericHistogram @values = @TVP READONLY
```

To get around this, my next approach was to simply pass in the table name as an nvarchar but it involves a lot of string manipulation and is quite ugly.

Does that seem like a reasonable workaround?  I'd much rather go with the first approach but I don't know if it's possible to populate a UDT "by reference".

Thanks

***Edit:**
Assuming I can quickly populate the @values UDT with ~2gigs worth of numeric data.  My function would look like this:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.numArray AS TABLE (
    number  real NOT NULL
);

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_numericHistogram (
    @values dbo.numArray READONLY,
    @numOfBreaks int = 10,
    @rangeMin float = NULL,
    @rangeMax float = NULL
)
RETURNS @output TABLE (
    lowerBound float NOT NULL,
    upperBound float NOT NULL,
    [count] int NOT NULL
)

BEGIN;
    DECLARE @intervalSize float;

    IF (@rangeMin IS NULL AND @rangeMax IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            @rangeMinOUT = MIN(number),
            @rangeMaxOUT = MAX(number)
        FROM @values;
    END

    SET @intervalSize = (@rangeMax - @rangeMin)/@numOfBreaks;

    INSERT INTO @output (lowerBound, upperBound, [count])
    SELECT  @rangeMin+@intervalSize*FLOOR(number/@intervalSize)                 AS lowerBound,
            @rangeMin+@intervalSize*FLOOR(number/@intervalSize)+@intervalSize   AS upperBound,
            COUNT(*)                                                            AS [count]
    FROM    (
            -- Special Case the max values.
            SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(number, @rangeMax), @rangeMax - 0.5 * @intervalSize - @rangeMin AS number
            FROM @values
            ) AS B
    GROUP BY FLOOR(number/@intervalSize);
    ';

    RETURN;
END;
GO
```

Otherwise, I'll have to pass in a table name, and the function bloats to something like this: (By the way, I'm not even sure if this would work as a function...perhaps I would need a stored procedure instead).

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_numericHistogram (
    @tableName nvarchar(200),
    @numericColumnName nvarchar(200),
    @numOfBreaks int = 10,
    @rangeMin float = NULL,
    @rangeMax float = NULL
)
RETURNS @output TABLE (
    lowerBound float NOT NULL,
    upperBound float NOT NULL,
    [count] int NOT NULL
)

BEGIN;
    DECLARE @intervalSize float;

    IF (@rangeMin IS NULL AND @rangeMax IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SQLQuery nvarchar(MAX);
        SET @SQLQuery = N'
            SELECT 
                @rangeMinOUT = CONVERT(float, MIN('+@numericColumnName+')),
                @rangeMaxOUT = CONVERT(float, MAX('+@numericColumnName+'))
            FROM '+@tableName+';
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery, N'rangeMinOUT nvarchar(50) OUTPUT, rangeMaxOUT nvarchar(50) OUTPUT', 
            @rangeMinOUT=@rangeMin OUTPUT, @rangeMaxOUT=@rangeMax OUTPUT;
    END

    SET @intervalSize = (@rangeMax - @rangeMin)/@numOfBreaks;

    SET @SQLQuery = N'
    INSERT INTO @output (lowerBound, upperBound, [count])
    SELECT  '+CONVERT(nvarchar, @rangeMin)+'+'+CONVERT(nvarchar, @intervalSize)+'*FLOOR(number/'+CONVERT(nvarchar, @intervalSize)+')                                        AS lowerBound,
            '+CONVERT(nvarchar, @rangeMin)+'+'+CONVERT(nvarchar, @intervalSize)+'*FLOOR(number/'+CONVERT(nvarchar, @intervalSize)+')+'+CONVERT(nvarchar, @intervalSize)+'   AS upperBound,
            COUNT(*)                                                                                                                                                        AS [count]
    FROM    (
            -- Special Case the max values.
            SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF('+@numericColumnName+', '+CONVERT(nvarchar, @rangeMax)+'), '+CONVERT(nvarchar, @rangeMax)+' - 0.5 * '+CONVERT(nvarchar, @intervalSize)+') - '+CONVERT(nvarchar, @rangeMin)+' AS number
            FROM '+@tableName+'
            ) AS B
    GROUP BY FLOOR(number/'+CONVERT(nvarchar, @intervalSize)+');'
    -- Return the results above
    RETURN;
END;
GO
```

Comment: You can create a table-valued function, which is kind of like populating a UDT "by reference".

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but I don't see how that would help.  Could you elaborate?  

If I created another user defined function that returned a table, I would still need to insert values into its output table.  Wouldn't that just reproduce what I was already doing?

Comment: If your current function returns a table, which isn't specified in your question, then yes.  But you don't call a function with EXEC the way your example shows.   If you need to populate a histogram table for use in a second statement, then just use the function AS that table:  "... JOIN dbo.MyTableValuedFunction(@TVP) tvf ON ...".   If you still aren't following, or don't see any relevance, please post more about what you intend to do with your histogram table once it is populated.

Comment: Have you considered a stored procedure.

Comment: I've edited the original post to contain both examples of the function.  I would much rather use the first example than the second one (with all of the CONVERTS and such)

Comment: If the second is already done then what is the big deal?

Comment: it doesn't work because I have to call the executesql stored procedure from my function.  It also feels like a hack.  The first version is also much more maintainable.

Though re: it feels like a hack, I'm not actually sure about that since I'm new to t-sql.

Comment: Why are you so stuck on a generic histogram?  Just write the select to a table and and when you need to use another table then edit the table name.